# How Form handling works in PHP?

Tags: php

I am learning PHP through w3schools. I am little bit confused of the execution flow of the page. I will attach a code example from w3schools.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  }
  
  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  }
    
  if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $website;
echo "<br>";
echo $comment;
echo "<br>";
echo $gender;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain how the execution flow goes on this form handling. Browser can't run the php script. In this example superglobal $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] used to refer the same html page. when we try to submit the page with empty field it shows the error message in screen. This is happening due to the fact php variable got its error value after submission. I think that after triggering the submit button. This page makes a request to the same page in the server using POST method and in the server we access the same form value using superglobal $_POST["name"],["email"] etc.. and finally the server throws the new html page. Am i right? or this validation is happening entirely in the frontend.

Comment: Sounds about right, yes. FWIW, that “test_input” function propagated by W3S is complete garbage. In fact, a lot of W3S is garbage. Look here for better resources: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info. See here for why that function in particular is garbage: http://kunststube.net/escapism.

Comment: PHP is run on the server. So unless Javascript is involved no validation in the frontend. The PHP manual also has a section on [Dealing with Forms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: Anything within `<?php` is PHP code which runs on the server. The result of this code is included in the response the server sends.

Answer (score 0):

In php the validation is happening entirely in the server ..

The frontend only validate things when JavaScript involved or you add field attributes like required , min , max.

I think w3 is good source to check small code snippets. but it's not good source to learn